# How to set the source of an image field dynamically in a multisite environement in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I have a multisite instance in Sitecore using SCORE and I would like to set the source of a common template image field to point to its corresponding media library folder.

Example:
My instance has Site A and Site B

In Site A, if a user clicks on browse of an image field it should open the Site A media folder and the same for Site B.

Comment: Did you had a Scaffolding to perform to generate the solution?

Comment: Yes, our instance is on Brainjocks Score platform that uses scaffolding to create tenants

Answer (score 0):

By default, SCORE does not provide this possibility. If you want that the site media specific container is selected, you will need to implement a custom field with a custom token in order to resolve the datasource of the media path